# rastertek tutorials - problems with third part of directx11 tut

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I've done third part of rastertek tutorial with DirectX11 and I have got a problem.
I have done everything before that and everything was OK and after paste last part of code and compile that I get Error message from that messagebox in graphicsclass.cpp...
And my question is: Is it problem that his code is for VS 2010 and I'm trying to compile that in VS 2012? Do I need to instal 2010?
If somebody has time, please, answear :)

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  Have you found the step that fails and checked the return value from that step?

Comment: Yes I tried debugging it and output of debug shows me a lot od dll files that was not opened. VS shows me: 
`'Engine.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file. `
But I have that file.... And every another file from long list...
My code with this error messagebox: 
`result = m_D3D->Initialize(screenWidth, screenHeight, VSYNC_ENABLED, hwnd, FULL_SCREEN, SCREEN_DEPTH, SCREEN_NEAR);

 if(!result)

 {

  
  MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize Direct3D.", L"Error", MB_OK);
  return false;
 }
`

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Geforce 310M don't have directx 11. Delete that question or close it :)